# Offset Array values by a number, for ng-repeating on bootstrap columns

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, lodash

I have an ng-repeat.

```
<div ng-repeat="setup in setupCategories | filterCategories: 'label' : 2" class="col-xs-6">
  {{setup.label}}
</div>
```

It is filtered/sorted alphabetically by a param value, in this case `label`

```
.filter('filterCategories', function() {
  return function(array, field, offset) {
    //Lodash sorts array by my field - label
    var sortedArray = _.sortBy(array, field);
    return sortedArray;
  };
})
```

I also have a parameter for offsetting, which is `2` in this example.

Right now this will ng-repeat as `col-xs-6`'s, turning

```
[Adam, Bob, Carol, Don, Eve, Frank]
```

into

```
Adam     Bob
Carol    Don
Eve      Frank
```

What I want to do is display my data like this. (easier to read)

```
Adam   Don
Bob    Eve
Carol  Frank
```

To do this, I need to offset my array values in my filter. So turn

```
[Adam, Bob, Carol, Don, Eve, Frank]
```

into

```
[Adam, Don, Bob, Eve, Carol, Frank]
```

So that it will automatically display in the proper order when repeated as `col-xs-6`. Is there a Javascript or Lodash way for me to easily offset my array values so that my filter function can specify `2` for `col-xs-6`'s, `3` for `col-xs-4`'s, ect...

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Don Eve Frank` in the second column? Otherwise I don't get how you want to rearrange the array values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very hard. This is what I have wrote recently by my self. It takes into account that items_count/column_count would be non-integer.

```
function arrangeByColumns(list, column_count) {
    var copy_list = list.slice();
    var result = [];
    var big_column_size = Math.floor(list.length / column_count) + 1;
    var big_column_count = list.length % column_count;

    for (var i = 0; i < big_column_count; i++) {
        result.push(copy_list.splice(0, big_column_size));
    }
    while (copy_list.length) {
        result.push(copy_list.splice(0, big_column_size - 1));
    }
    return result;
}

function flattenColumns(list) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < list[0].length; i++) {
        list.forEach(function (value) {
            if (value[i])
                result.push(value[i]);
        });
    }
    ;
    return result;
}

var array = ['Adam', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'Don', 'Eve', 'Frank'];
console.log(flattenColumns(arrangeByColumns(array, 2)));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for edge case logic! From what I gathered, `arrangeByColumns` splits up the list by a `column_count` number of arrays. And `flattenColumns` is doing a "zip" on the array of arrays. Correct?